# How do I discuss the zeros of a cubic equation in an open interval?

Tags: calculus, polynomials, roots

Discuss the zeroes of $2x^3 - 3x^2 - 12x + 2 $ on the interval $ (- 2, 5). $

Comment: I am aware that this question is somewhat calculus related, but to go about it puzzles me.

Comment: You will get slated for not saying anything about what you have tried. In the meantime, try to draw a graph of the polynomial using its derivative and maybe the derivative of its derivative to inform you about its local maxima an minima.

Answer (score 1):

In here you must apply the Bolzano's Theorem, that basically states that:

> "If a continuous function defined on an interval is sometimes positive and sometimes negative, it must be 0 at some point."

Now let's see if there is a zero in $(-2,5)$:

$$f(-2)=-2$$
$$f(5)= 117$$

As we can see, do exist a root in this interval. Now we can apply some numerical methods in order to approximate (as we want to the) desired the root. Let's use the Bisection Method:

The steps are: 1st) we are going to divide the interval in which there is a zero;
2nd) evaluate $f$ in the middle point and see if it is positive or negative;
3rd) repeat again.

In this case the middle point is: $p_0=\dfrac{3}{2}$
Now let's follow the 2nd step: $f(1.5)=-16$
As we can see the new interval is $(1.5,5)$

$p_1=3.25$;
$f(3.25)=-0.03125$;
$(3.25,5)$.

$\cdots$
$\cdots$

As we can see, $3.25$ is already close to the root, however, only at infinity, you get exact result.

**EDIT**

A method that requires some calculus understanding is the Newton Method.